# Is this Du'a after Wudu proven to be Sahih or Da'if?

Tags: dua, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, islamic-scholar

<sup>Before posing my specific question, I would like to state that there is obviously a great difference to ask about a narration's authenticity which is discussed to be either Hasan or Da'if. Interestingly, the following Hadith, like many others, is considered to be proven Sahih by the Muhaddith Shaykh Albani in his Sahih At-Tirmidhi and other books (and Ibn al-Qayyim), yet Al-Hafiz Ibn Hajar Asqalani deemed it to be Da'if (not proven) in Nata'ij al-Afkar ([1/243](https://archive.org/details/WAQ101273/01_101273/page/n242/mode/2up)-6).</sup>

Narrated in At-Tirmidhi ([55](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:55)), which Abu I'sa deemed to be not proven, that the Prophet (ﷺ) said, after making Wudu and the Shahadah:

> [...] "*Allahum-majalni minat-tau-wabin, waj'alni minal mutatahhirin*" (Ya Allah, make me among the repentant, and make me among those who purify themselves) - "*Then, eight Gates of Paradise are opened for him, that (he) may enter by whichever of them (he) wishes.*"

I would like to know which argument by those two scholars, and if possible from other Hadith-Scholars, is closer to the truth to understand if this Du'a is proven to be Sahih or Da'if (not proven)?

Comment: Excellent question but I highly doubt there can be a definitive answer as here we have two great scholars of Hadith on an disagreement. With all due respect to them (may Allah have mercy on their souls) I am eager for someone from the community to enlighten us in this matter and provide a better understanding in this dispute.

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, I would also ask this question at www.hadithanswers.com

Comment: Imam at-Trimidhi already pointed at a weakness in his comment. The point is that this hadith has a sahih part and a part which is an addition to sahih which is not. As the different hadith parts are covered in a whole lot of sources it iould need much analysis to give a good answer however this was done in this article on [alukah](https://www.alukah.net/sharia/0/72664/) to a certain depth (the analysis of the hadith and its parts is longer than the whole article as you may see in the footnote. A big weakness actually is at-Tirmidhi's teacher as his report contradicts more reliable ones.